# Python Loop iteration with replacement of null values in timeseries of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to replace null values with value of the list below in Python.
Value will be same for any item through out the list if its not null.

example of list

```
[[1538140080000, None], [1538140140000, None], [1538140200000, None], [1538140260000, None], [1538140320000, None], [1538140380000, 92881926.0], [1538140440000, 92881926.0]]
```

I would like to get the output to be

```
[[1538140080000, 92881926.0], [1538140140000, 92881926.0], [1538140200000, 92881926.0], [1538140260000, 92881926.0], [1538140320000, 92881926.0], [1538140380000, 92881926.0], [1538140440000, 92881926.0]]
```

In the list any one of the (key, value) will have the required value (apart from null), which I want to replace with for all the keys of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a list comprehension can easily do the job

```
l = [[q if q else 0 for q in i] for i in l]
```

**Output**

```
[[1538140080000, 0], [1538140140000, 0], [1538140200000, 0], [1538140260000, 0], [1538140320000, 0], [1538140380000, 92881926.0], [1538140440000, 92881926.0]]
```

**updated**

```
var = [[i[q] for i in l if i[q]] for q in range(len(l[0]))]
l  = [[q if q else var[w][0] for w,q in enumerate(i)] for i in l]
```

**output**

```
[[1538140080000, 92881926.0], [1538140140000, 92881926.0], [1538140200000, 92881926.0], [1538140260000, 92881926.0], [1538140320000, 92881926.0], [1538140380000, 92881926.0], [1538140440000, 92881926.0]]
```

Comment: this results in a flattened list though.

Comment: ups my bad... fixed :)

Comment: better. list-comps are the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [[1538140080000, None], [1538140140000, None], [1538140200000, None], [1538140260000, None], [1538140320000, None], [1538140380000, 92881926.0], [1538140440000, 92881926.0]]

replacement = next(filter(None, list(zip(*l))[1]))

for sl in l:
     for i, x in enumerate(sl):
         if x is None:
             sl[i] = replacement
print(l)
```

outputs

```
[[1538140080000, 92881926.0],
 [1538140140000, 92881926.0],
 [1538140200000, 92881926.0],
 [1538140260000, 92881926.0],
 [1538140320000, 92881926.0],
 [1538140380000, 92881926.0],
 [1538140440000, 92881926.0]]
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. I need to replace the null with value of list(key). here 92881926.0 and this value should get replaced, where ever null present in the list(this value will be same for the entire list. once or more times in the list)

Comment: You should modify the question, I think.  to fetch that key you'd need to get that `replacement = max(map(lambda (a,b):b))` should do (because the max of `None` and a number is that number).

Comment: @Rahul updated the answer to find the replacement value.

Comment: @Alex: Appreciate your efforts. that solves my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Could be a one-liner, if you hard-code replacement.

Also, if you can allow lazy evaluation, you can eliminate the list(...) call.

```
replacement = 0
l = list( map(lambda (a,b): [a,replacement if b == None else b], l) )
```

Comment: could be shorter `map(lambda (a,b): [a,b if b else replacement], l)`

Comment: the required should be  [[1538140080000, 92881926.0],
 [1538140140000, 92881926.0],
 [1538140200000, 92881926.0],
 [1538140260000, 92881926.0],
 [1538140320000, 92881926.0],
 [1538140380000, 92881926.0],
 [1538140440000, 92881926.0]]

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, Pandas offers vectorised methods:

```
import pandas as pd

L = [[1538140080000, None], [1538140140000, None], [1538140200000, None],
     [1538140260000, None], [1538140320000, None], [1538140380000, 92881926.0],
     [1538140440000, 92881926.0]]

res = pd.DataFrame(L).bfill().ffill().values.tolist()

print(res)

[[1538140080000.0, 92881926.0], [1538140140000.0, 92881926.0], [1538140200000.0, 92881926.0],
 [1538140260000.0, 92881926.0], [1538140320000.0, 92881926.0], [1538140380000.0, 92881926.0],
 [1538140440000.0, 92881926.0]]
```

Comment: list may not have key, value at the end of list all the time

Comment: its random but atlest any one element will have the key and value without Null and the value will be same for any other iteration it occurs in the list

Comment: Ex [[1538140080000, None], [1538140140000, 92881926.0], [1538140200000, None],
     [1538140260000, None], [1538140320000, None], [1538140380000, 92881926.0],
     [1538140440000, 0]]

Comment: @Rahul, Then use `bfill` then `ffill`. Have updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the value that is not `None`, since it will only ever be one value we can use `set`

Redefine items in `l` as `[i[0], *value]`

```
value = set([y for x, y in l if y != None])
l = [[i[0], *value] for i in l]
```

> ```
> [[1538140080000, 92881926.0], [1538140140000, 92881926.0], [1538140200000, 92881926.0], [1538140260000, 92881926.0], [1538140320000, 92881926.0], [1538140380000, 92881926.0], [1538140440000, 92881926.0]]
> ```